# Differentiate pages with same url

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento

I have a script that runs on two different pages, one for orders and one for quotes. These pages have an identical url followed by a dynamic string. What can I do to have this script do one thing on one page and one thing on another?

Edit: I wasn't very clear on this looking back, the current selected answer does work well for what I asked, however it shouldn't be used with Magento. Magento has built in methods for determining this information, and you would want to override it rather than inject script into the adminhtml code.

Comment: Have it look at the contents of the dynamic string. The parameters will be available to PHP via the $_REQUEST variable. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: You can pass in a parameter to show whether the scripts is being called for Orders or for Quotes; then, your script can check the parameter, and run the appropriate code - I generally use `include` to do that, as that way, the code for the separate sections can be kept in different files.

Comment: @JonathanM Not to say your comment is bad, I understood he wanted to do it client side for a script.

Comment: Good point, dystroy. @Nathan, is the script client-side or server-side?

Comment: Preferably server side. It's part of the control panel so it's not necessary to reduce work in this area.

Comment: I'm going to look into $_REQUEST here real quick.

Comment: Here's an example URL real quick:index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/273151/ The only difference between this url and the other URL is the number at the end. The number is an order id. In this particular system quotes and orders are treated the exact same, and are called in the exact same way. I guess basically this is the same page, just two different versions of it. It's all based on a template system.

Comment: @Nathan, updated my answer based on your last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the parameters from the URL via $_REQUEST in PHP. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

**EDIT**:
I see from your comments that your URL is like `http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/273151/`.

If it's always this way without any query parameters, then you may want to parse the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable in PHP.

(see here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You can get an array of these path parts by doing:

```
$myPathArray = explode($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/');
```

Then you can get that last, differentiating, part of the path like this:

```
if (count($myPathArray)) {
    $orderId = $myPathArray[count($myPathArray)-1];
} else {
    $orderId = ''; // or whatever you please
}
```

Comment: Why is everyone saying $_REQUEST, wouldn't $_GET be all that's required?

Comment: $_REQUEST is the combination of $_POST and $_GET, so you don't have to know the request method.

Answer (score 2):

You can check what's in the URL, for example with this :

```
function getUrlParameter = function(name, defaultValue) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( document.location.href );
if( results == null ) return defaultValue;
else return results[1];
};
```

If your URL is `test.php?a=toto` then you'll have toto in pageA :

```
var pageA = getUrlParameter("toto");
```

EDIT : if you just want the end of the path part, look at `document.location.pathname`

Comment: The URL is identical until this random string. For instance page A is http://asdf.com/place/stuff/1j2hds943nh3qlx Page B is http://asdf.com/place/stuff/2kljsdf934hzsnvl. test() could return true for both or neither.

Comment: Are your pages really in PHP ?

Comment: @Nathan it's *not* the same URL. If there are different parameters in it, then they are different URLs.

Comment: @dystroy, he updated in the main comments that he's wanting server-side solutions.

Comment: It's a bit of everything. JS/PHP/AJAX

Comment: @JonathanM So your answer looks like the good one but what OP really wants isn't clear to me, especially following his exemples as first comment of this answer.

Comment: @dystroy, yeah, you asked the right question: client or server? Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

If your url variable names are different on each page you could use an if statement

```
if (isset($_GET['vara'])) {
    // Do thing A
}
elseif (isset($_GET['varb'])) {
    // Do thing b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$_GET](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGEQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php&ei=zF_ST-6QE8ej2QW8k4GJDw&usg=AFQjCNHF-g0UEkXh5Zf9CGnieUs-jU2HHQ&sig2=p2Th21vWBlTC8Ta86NjEZg) to retrieve variables passed in the URL. If your new at this Tizag has some [easy to read tutorials](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php). With the values of variables being passed, you can figure out which page you are coming from.